# mysql get substring offset (indexOf)?

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to get the offset of a substring, in mysql?

IE

"hello everybody i'm a newbie programmer" "everybody" offset 6

i'm looking for the equivalent of indexOf in java/javascript

thanks!

Answer (score 18):

sorry, found by myself

```
INSTR(str, substr)
```

Comment: Can you give me the check for posting the answer at the same time. Thanks!